# The state passed from the Link shows undefined on the passed page in Reactjs,why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've passed the state `movie` from the component `MovieCard` through the Link component.

The state displays in console in the home page where `MovieCard` is rendered when its clicked but the state is not displayed like it shows undefined on details page.

I tried everything like checked the route path, tried to see if the state is being passed or not but its not working as expected. I want to send details from `MovieCard` and display those on separate Details page

```jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MovieCard = ({ poster, movie, id }) => {
  console.log("Movie card detailsssssss", movie);

  return (
    <div className="sm:w-[300px] sm:h-[300px] w-[100%] h-[300px] ">
      <Link
        to={{ pathname: `/detail/${id}`, state: { movie } }}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        <img
          src={poster}
          className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-md cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 transition-transform duration-300"
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Detail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const detail = state?.movie;
  console.log("Details", detail);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Details page</h1>
      <p>Movie id : {id}</p>
      {detail ? <p>Movie detail: {detail.title}</p> : <p>Loading...</p>}
      <button onClick={() => window.history.back()}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Detail;
```

Comment: State is passed in the `to` prop if you are using `react-router-dom@5`. ***BUT*** if you are using `react-router-dom@6` `state` is a prop directly on the `Link` component, e.g. `<Link to=".." state={{ ... }} />`.

Comment: @DrewReese i've passed the state according to you. the id in the detail page is correct and shows up but the state is still not getting displayed.
 <Link
        // to={{ pathname: `/detail/${id}`, state: { movie } }}
        to={`/detail/${id}`}
        state={movie}
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
      >
        <img
          src={poster}
          className="w-full h-full object-cover rounded-md cursor-pointer hover:scale-105 transition-transform duration-300"
        />
      </Link>
here's my code after your suggesstion

Comment: Passing `state={movie}` means that `location.state` ***is*** the movie object. If you want to access `location.state.movie` in the target component then pass `state={{ movie }}`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: it's still showing the value undefined in the Details page.
import React from "react";
import { useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Detail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { state } = useLocation();

  const detail = state?.movie;
  console.log("Details", detail);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Details page</h1>
      <p>Movie id : {id}</p>
      {detail ? <p>Movie detail: {detail.title}</p> : <p>Loading...</p>}
      <button onClick={() => window.history.back()}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Detail;

Comment: Is the `movie` prop passed to `MovieCard` defined? Can you confirm also what version of React-Router you are using?

Comment: in MovieCard componetnt it shows undefined but when i click on MovieCard it gives the same detail of the card i just clicked

Comment: If `movie` is undefined in `MovieCard` then you may need to look upstream where it is passed. Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] if you need more help? The scope of the topic of this post appears to be creeping.